# What is the difference between the 4 "Prettier" VS Code extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

[Prettier Extension Search VS COde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1ZxT.png)

I see **Prettier** - Code Formatter,  **Prettier Now**, **Prettier - Code Formatter**, **Prettier+**. What is the difference between these four?

Answer (score 1):

`Prettier Now (remimarsal.prettier-now)` and
`Prettier - Code Formatter(SimonSiefke.prettier-vscode)` are both deprecated. => **Should not be used anymore.**

`Prettier (esbenp.prettier-vscode)` which is also called `Prettier - Code Formatter` in VS Code is the **official extension.**

`Prettier+ (svipas.prettier-plus)` is an expansion of the official Prettier Extension, but I don't see the benefit of it over the official prettier extension, as the supported languages are the same and the differences aren't listed in the description. You could check the [changelogs](https://github.com/svipas/vscode-prettier-plus/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), but I guess it will not be worth it.

****Another (actually useful)One****

Last but not least there is the Extension `Prettier Eslint (rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint)` which is combining the formatting functionalities of Prettier with the linter functionalities of [EsLint](https://eslint.org/)

It uses prettier and Eslint under the hood, so you can expect the same features. When formatting with Prettier Eslint, it first applies the Prettier Formatting and than the Eslint linting.

Like described [here](https://github.com/idahogurl/vs-code-prettier-eslint#prerequisites), you first need to install Eslint and Prettier (not the VS Code extensions) locally in your project or globally, using a package manager like `npm` or `yarn`